# How to sum_if on vectors in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe with casflows

```
cashflow <- round(runif(53, min=-1000, max=1000),0)
dni <- seq(as.Date("2017/1/1"), as.Date("2017/12/31"), by = "week")
df1 <- data.frame(dni, cashflow)
```

EDIT: important! dates in df1 are not unique. There are multiple entries for some days. Let's imitate it like this

```
df1 <- rbind(df1,df1)
```

and another one where I want to have balance for every day depending on flows from df1

```
dni <- seq(as.Date("2017/1/1"), as.Date("2017/12/31"), by = "days")
balance <- rep(1,length(dni))
df2 <- data.frame(dni, balance)
```

My idea was to sum for each date in df2 values from `df1$cashflow` that has earlier or equal date. I've tried this

```
df2$poziom <- sum(df1[ which(df1$dni < df2$dni),]$cashflow)
```

and that

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% filter(dni< as.Date("2017-04-30")) %>% select(cashflow)
```

and in both cases got this error

```
In `<.default`(df1$dni, df2$dni) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I suspect the problem is messing two vectors of different length in `which` and `filter`, but I dont know how else to sum the values I want with one line of code operating on vectors.

Comment: Do you mean the cumulative sum for each date? You can `merge` `df1` and `df2` and use `cumsum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the calculation over `df2$dni`, using e.g. sapply for convenient output.

```
df2$poziom <- sapply(df2$dni, function(day){sum(df1$cashflow[df1$dni <= day])})
```

If `df1$dni` is guaranteed to be a subset of `df2$dni` and there are no duplicities in either, you can use `merge`, fill `NAs` with `0` and then `cumsum`, as mentioned in a comment by DJV.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can do this:

```
require(tidyverse)

fullDF <- merge(df1, df2, by = "dni", all = TRUE)

fullDF %>% 
  mutate(Sum = cumsum(replace_na(cashflow, 0)))
```

Dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
cashflow <- round(runif(53, min=-1000, max=1000),0)
dni <- seq(as.Date("2017/1/1"), as.Date("2017/12/31"), by = "week")
df1 <- data.frame(dni, cashflow)

dni <- seq(as.Date("2017/1/1"), as.Date("2017/12/31"), by = "days")
balance <- rep(1,length(dni))
df2 <- data.frame(dni, balance)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very nice solution to the reproducible example i presented. Unfortunately it was not close enough to the real one i have. The problem is that dates in `df1` are not unique - there are few entries for some days. In that case your solution doesn't work, as there are repeated dates in `fullDF`. How to solve that? I'm updating the original qquestion as well.